# Visual Studio always re-compiles code even if it hadn't changed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, incremental-build

After some changes to my project, Visual Studio started to always re-compiles all sources, causing all dependent project to also re-compile, slowing down development considerably. Why is that?

- Happens only when `XML documentation file` is checked and there's some file with `Copy always`. If you change either of these, the sources don't get re-compiled.
- Happens only when compiling inside Visual Studio - when compiling using `MSBuild` from commandline, the sources don't get re-compiled.
- Visual Studio 2012 Update 4.

Comment: I use VS 2013 Update 2 and I see the same unwanted behavior: projects recompiled when no changes happened to the source code. It happens even though I do not have "XML documentation file" checked in any projects of my solution. So there are other reasons as well. :-(

Comment: Well, you can investigate it the described in my answer below, and report your findings.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in Visual Studio, when project has `XML documentation file` checked some files with `Copy always`.

**Repro:**

1. Create new project - C# class library.
2. Project Properties => Build => check `XML documentation file`
3. Project => Add => New Item => Text file `TextFile1.txt`
4. Change TextFile1.txt `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`
5. Right-click project => build

   - project compiles
6. Right-click project => build

**Expected:** Project shouldn't be built, build output should say:

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Actual:** Project is build, output is:

```
------ Build started: Project: ClassLibrary1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  ClassLibrary1 -> bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Intestigation:** Turning on detailed log, you see:

```
Target "CoreCompile" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" from project "ClassLibrary1.csproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Building target "CoreCompile" completely.
Output file "bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.XML" does not exist.
```

Looking in procmon, you see that devenv.exe renames "ClassLibrary1.XML" into "vsA381.tmp" just before MSBuild.exe runs. Stack trace for the rename:

```
KERNEL32!MoveFileW+0x17
csproj!CMoveOutOfTheWayScope::EnterScope+0x85
csproj!CVsProjBuildableProjectCfg::StartBuildProcessWithTarget+0x50b
csproj!CVsProjBuildableProjectCfg::StartBuildProcess+0xc
csproj!CVsProjBuildableProjectCfg::StartBuildEx+0x15
msenv!CSUIBuilder::DoBuild+0x1a3
msenv!CSUIBuilder::Run+0x66
```